# Use ssl certificate on the GCP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, gcp-load-balancer

I have one load balancer on the GCP.
my project uses multi-domain and it is possible that add domains on after.
when I create a certificate with the google-managed certificate, I can't edit the certificate and add a domain.
I know I can remove the certificate and create a new certificate.
but not good because domains will not be certified for a while.

Do I have to get a certificate from somewhere else?
Is it possible to get a certificate that I can add to that domain later without changing the public key and private key?
What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancers support multiple certificates. If you need to add another domain, create/add a new certificate.

[Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs)